# Add Custom Url to WP All Import with function editor

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

Hi guys and thanks for the help.
I have a remote server that implements an OAI-PMH interface to collect data from a database.
I want import those records using wp all import through 'download from url'.
Since i can query the oai interface with a url that can contain customs parameters (because i don't want the entire collection), it is possible to use the function editor of wp_allimport to change or attach (dynamic) parameters to the url before the import is executed? And then schedule the same?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. make sure to add your current progress (code you are working with), actual output and desired output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter. You cannot use the function editor in this case but you can put this code into `functions.php` of your (child) theme:

```
function my_wp_all_import_feed_url( $url ) {
    return $url . '?something=else';
}

add_filter( 'wp_all_import_feed_url', 'my_wp_all_import_feed_url', 10, 4 );
```

This code sample assumes that URL has a trailing `/`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've resolved the problem with a dynamic redirection. i've added a simple php script (so wpallimport point to a static path), then inside the script i've made a dynamic redirection to the real path. this because the query parameters depends on the month of the schedule, and they have to be filled automatically

Comment: Great news @frifab - I invite you to share your solution as a separate answer and mark that as the correct one.